# REST returning [object Object]

Tags: rest

I converted a CAML query to REST and one of the fields that displayed the data using CAML now appears as [object Object] when using REST. Why and how to correct.

Thanks

Comment: Please post the script to understand it.

Answer (score 3):

Your REST result is an Object (either JSON or XML) so if you display that using JavaScript it is displayed as [object Object]

You have to convert the Object to a String

```
JSON.stringify( yourRESTobject )
```

or display it in the F12 DEV console

```
console.dir( yourRESTobject );
```